# Índice Invertido Python

Tags: python-3.x

**Problema:**

Preciso criar um Dicionário de índices invertidos onde devo tokenizar a string, remover as stopwords e extrair o radical da palavra (stemmer) tudo utilizando o pacote nltk.
A saída do programa deve ser um dicionário de dicionários contendo os radicais das palavras extraídas junto das quantidades de vezes em que eles aparecem na sentença.

**Dúvida:**

O stemmer que realizo sobre a sentença me retorna apenas a única aparição da palavra tokenizada, porem preciso que apareça todas as vezes que se encontra na sentença.

Exemplo da saída atual (preciso que aparece 'cas' todas as vezes que a palavra 'casa' é encontrada):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Outra questão:**

Como concatenar todos os dicionários em um único?

Saída do programa:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Código:**

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

def readBaseFile(fileName):
    with open(fileName, 'r') as fileRead:
        lines = fileRead.read().splitlines()

    fileRead.close()
    
    return lines


def countFrequency(my_list, fileNumber):
    freq = {}

    for key in my_list:
        if (key not in freq):
            freq[key] = {fileNumber:1}
        else:
            freq[key] = {fileNumber:freq[key]+1}

    print(freq)

    return freq

def readLinesInSubfile(linesInBaseFile, fileNumber):
    tokenizeWord = tokenizer.tokenize(linesInBaseFile[0])
    print(tokenizeWord)

    tokenizeWord = {stemmer.stem(word) for word in tokenizeWord if not word in stopwords}

    print(tokenizeWord)

    return countFrequency(tokenizeWord, fileNumber)

def subfilesOfBaseFile(linesInBaseFile, fileNumber):
    linesInSubfiles = {}

    for files in range(len(linesInBaseFile)):
        linesInSubfiles = readBaseFile('base1/'+linesInBaseFile[files])

        dictionary = readLinesInSubfile(linesInSubfiles, fileNumber)

        fileNumber = fileNumber + 1

    return dictionary

stopwords = nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("portuguese")
stemmer = nltk.stem.RSLPStemmer()
tokenizer = nltk.RegexpTokenizer(r"\w+")
def main():
    fileToRead = "base1/base.txt"
    fileNumber = 1

    linesInBaseFile = readBaseFile(fileToRead)
    print(linesInBaseFile)

    subfilesOfBaseFile(linesInBaseFile, fileNumber)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```